# Trigger not being called, why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

So I have the following function that the trigger calls when I insert rows into a table called 'auxi'. It seems not to work since I have the value 'id_usuario' with NULL on my table and the trigger is supposed to avoid that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION firstRestriction() RETURNS Trigger
AS $$
DECLARE
    operation boolean = false;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'HERE %',operation;
    operation = operation OR isNULL(new.periodo, 'periodo');
    operation = operation OR isNULL(new.id_usuario, 'id_usuario');
    operation = operation OR isNULL(new.fecha_hora_retiro, 'fecha_hora_retiro');
    operation = operation OR isNULL(new.origen_estacion, 'origen_estacion');
    operation = operation OR isNULL(new.destino_estacion, 'destino_estacion');
    operation = operation OR isNULL(new.tiempo_uso, 'tiempo_uso');
/*operation = operation OR isLessThanZero(new.tiempo_uso, 'tiempo_uso');*/

    IF operation THEN
        raise notice 'No se pudo insertar % % % % % %',new.periodo, new.id_usuario, new.fecha_hora_retiro,new.origen_estacion 
                                                   ,new.destino_estacion, new.tiempo_uso; 
        return NULL;
    ELSE

        return new;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER checkFirstRestriction
 BEFORE INSERT ON auxi
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE firstRestriction();
```

And then I do

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cond1()
 RETURNS VOID AS $$

 BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO auxi
    SELECT *
    FROM datos_recorrido;

 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Also isNull is the following function

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isNULL(field anyelement, information TEXT) RETURNS boolean
 AS $$
 BEGIN
     IF field IS NULL THEN
      raise notice 'El campo % es NULL', information;
      return true;
   ELSE
      return false;
   END IF;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then at certain point I call my funciton cond1().
I think my trigger is never being called. Could that be possible?

Comment: Looks like the trigger could easily be replaced by `NOT NULL` constraints, which is probably preferable. Also what is `isnull()`? Is that a function you wrote? AFAIK, there is no `isnull()` in Postgres, that's an SQL Server thing (and there it does not return a boolean (or bit as SQL Server has no true boolean), but the value if it is not null or the replacement, so it wouldn't match your use anyway)). If you wrote it, please show the code for `isnull()`. If not, your trigger function might just not work because it calls an undefined function.

Comment: @stickybit sorry, I just updated my question, it's a function I wrote.